# DbMigration move column with data

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, database-migration

I have two tables: A and B. Both tables are filled with data.

Table A contain column: **col**. I want to move **col** with data from table A to table B. After all I want to drop **col** from table A. Should I write raw sql to copy data or there are method to copy data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your migration will need to add `col` to B, then use raw SQL to update B from A, then drop `col` from A.

```
AddColumn("B", "col", c => c...);
Sql("update B set col = ...");
DropColumn("A", "col");
```